# pytest error when using parametrize & xfail

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using pytest for automation testing
i'm trying to use parametrize with xfail.
Option 1 works -the tuple is written dircely inside the list
Option 2 failed :with error :must be equal to the number of values (1): (trying to build list comperhension)

Option 2 example : that failed ( this is the one i need to use in my code)
note that in data_driven list of tuple everything is ok and have correct tuple

```
def build_dd():
    with open('xxx/dd_ee.json') as dd_file:
        dd_json = json.load(dd_file)
    data_driven = [tuple(scenario.values()) for scenario in dd_json['scenarios']]
    z=[pytest.param(new_tuple_with_xfail, marks=pytest.mark.xfail) for new_tuple_with_xfail in 
    data_driven ]
    return z


@pytest.mark.parametrize("val1,va2", build_dd(),)
def test_eval(val1, val2):
    assert val1 != val2
    print(11)
```

option 1 that passes:

```
def build_dd():
    
    x = [pytest.param(1,2, marks=pytest.mark.xfail)]
    return x


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "val1,va2", build_dd(),)
def test_eval(val1, val2):
    assert val1 != val2
    print(11)
```

in the screenshot i can be see clearly the difference between x which is ok and y
[image]
please advice,
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `pytest.param` needs 1 positional argument for each parameter, but you've only given it a single tuple argument.  The solution is to unpack the tuple using the `*args` syntax.  In other words, `z` needs to be defined like so:

```
z = [
    pytest.param(*new_tuple_with_xfail, marks=pytest.mark.xfail)
    for new_tuple_with_xfail in data_driven
]
```

You might also find the [parametrize_from_file](https://parametrize-from-file.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package useful.  It handles the task of loading test cases from JSON files, and has built-in support for adding marks to specific test cases.

Comment: checking it and update,thank in advance !